# When doing regression, is it possible to normalize just certain variables?

Tags: regression, econometrics, regression-coefficients, normalization

I have a dataset containing categorical variables (0-1), variables with range 0-99 and an income variable with range 0-100k. I want apply linear regression, logit etc but I guess that different scales would bring disruptive effects on the results. Can I normalize just the income variable, bringing it on the same scale as the 0-99 variables, or should I normalize the whole dataset?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Why normalize at all? That approach has gotten popular in deep learning due to numerical issues when it comes to convergence of optimization methods, but the optimization in linear regression is much more straightforward and lacks many of those issues. (There is a closed-form solution, for example.)

Comment: So there's no need for that when doing inference?

Comment: Most least squares programs automatically standardize the data (or do something similar) under the hood.  There are some exceptions, so it pays to watch out when the ranges of your variables differ by many orders of magnitude.  The commonest situation is the use of dates, which may be represented as seconds since a starting time (typically 1970).  As a practical matter, it is usually helpful to adopt units of measurement at the outset of your analysis that tend to be close to $1$ in magnitude. For instance, I would represent income in terms of thousands per year.

Comment: Standard linear regression is affine equivariant, meaning that results when multiplying, dividing or shifting variables by a constant will be equivalent. Therefore normalizing doesn't make a difference for the computations and inference. However, doing it will make the sizes of the estimated regression coefficients comparable. (Not sure how big an advantage that is, because they can be easily misinterpreted, so care is needed anyway.)

Comment: ok thank you all very much!